# Como puedo insertar un array de tipo JSON en php

Tags: php, javascript, json, foreach

### se va llenando conforme el usuario va ingresando los datos pueden ser 3 ,20,6 datos eso depende de cuantos se registren en el array en JavaScript saco la suma de ese array y después convierto a JSON y lo mando a php

Anteriormente me costo mandar el array de tipo json a mi archivo de php ya pude lograr que lo resiviera solo que ahora que lo quiero insertar he tenido error no me inserta los datos me manda directamente a mi script de error he intentado con 3 opciones para recorrer el JSON que las muestro mas adelante ##

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
    var_dump($array);
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas(fecha, dinero) VALUES (DEFAULT, :fecha ,:dinero )");
  //opcion 3
    foreach ($array->{"data"} as $index => $value) { // itera por cada elemento 0,1,2..
        $ins->bindParam(":fecha", $fecha);
        $ins->bindParam(":dinero", $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        //$ins->bindParam(':Total', $total,PDO :: PARAM_STR);
    }
    // he intentado con estas opcion para insetar mi array de tipo JSON
 OPCION 1:
       foreach ($array->data as $index=>$value) { // itera por cada elemento 0,1,2..
        $ins->bindParam(1,$fecha);
        $ins->bindParam(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         //$ins->bindParam(':Total', $total,PDO :: PARAM_STR);
       }
  Opcion 2:
        foreach ($array->{"data"} as $dineroS) { // itera por cada elemento 0,1,2..
         $ins->bindParam(1,$fecha);
         $ins->bindParam(2, $dinero->{" "}, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          //$ins->bindParam(':Total', $total,PDO :: PARAM_STR);
    }
  //y una 3era opcion que es la que esta en el codigo sin comentar
    if ($ins->execute()) {
        $registro = "<script>
         Swal.fire(
             'EXITO!',
             'Registros Guardados',
             'success'
           )
         </script>
         ";
        echo $registro;
        $ins = null;
        $con = null;
    } else {
        $error = "<script>
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Datos no guardados',
            text: 'Intente de nuevo',

          })
         </script>
         ";
         echo $error;
    }

    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo a tomar en cuenta en tu query, el campo que pones `DEFAULT` a que campo corresponde? Si se trata de algún id y lo estas declarando en tu `ÌNSERT`, debes indicarlo cuando declaras los campos que vas a insertar. `INSERT INTO ventas( id, fecha, dinero) VALUES (DEFAULT, :fecha ,:dinero )` o `INSERT INTO ventas(fecha, dinero) VALUES (:fecha ,:dinero )`

Comment: haa ok, anteriormente así lo maneje y si me insertaba los datos sin necesidad de declararlo lo pondre . tendra algo que ver coneso?

Comment: Con ese cambio intenta probar algunas de las propuestas de `foreach` que te respondieron. Prueba aquellas donde pasaba el `foreach` pero tiraba el error del `Swal`.

Comment: Vota lo mismo .

Comment: Imprime los errores de la conexión a la base de datos. Utiliza `echo print_r($ins->errorInfo());` en el else.

Comment: Sale esto:  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(30)
  }
}
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
)
1

Comment: Intenta aplicar la propuesta que te indique en la respuesta, al parecer el problema no es tu json y los foreach sino la construcción de tu query. Seria interesante (si persiste el problema) ver cual es la estructura de tu tabla (el CREATE).

Comment: haa va gracias intentare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, la propuesta a tu problema es el siguiente:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true); //lo convierte en array php
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //En algun lugar del codigo supongo que defines la conexion con $con
    $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas(id, fecha, total, dinero) VALUES (NULL, :fecha , :total, :dinero )");

    //Nos ayudamos con algunas variables para validar y depurar la operacion
    $insert_error['success'] = true; //Mientras se mantenga eb true significa que no hubo errores
    $insert_error['error'] = array(); //Almacenamos los errores

    foreach ($array['data'] as $value){
        $ins->bindParam(":fecha", $fecha);
        $ins->bindParam(":total", 0, PDO::PARAM_INT); //puse 0, pero si lo tienes calculado lo pones ahi
        $ins->bindParam(":dinero", $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if (!$ins->execute()) {
            $insert_error['success'] = false;
            $insert_error['error'][] = $ins->errorInfo();
        }
    }

    //Si no hubo errores se muestra mensaje de exito, sino muestra detalle y mensaje
    if ($insert_error['success']) {
        $registro = "<script>
         Swal.fire(
             'EXITO!',
             'Registros Guardados',
             'success'
           )
         </script>
         ";
        echo $registro;
    } 
    else {
        $error = "<script>
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Datos no guardados',
            text: 'Intente de nuevo',

          })
         </script>
         ";
        echo $error;
        echo print_r($insert_error['error']);
    }

}
```

Como se trata de un multi-insert según la cantidad de elementos que traes de tu `JSON`, se ejecuta la consulta en cada iteración del `foreach`.

Comment: con la propuesta que me diste me da error en el foreach

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\panaderia\administrador\admin\procesos\Procesoventa.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\panaderia\administrador\admin\procesos\Procesoventa.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Comment: Pusiste el  `true` en el `json_decode`? `$array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);` https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: mmm si , me manda al script del error

Comment: Si te manda al script del error (donde esta el `Swal`) es problema de como  estas preparando el query SQL. Muéstranos como es la estructura de la tabla `ventas`, quizas hay algun campo `not null` o algún problema con tu id. Actualiza tu pregunta con el script actual que tienes.

Comment: hooooo , voy a poner la captura

Comment: Actualice el query, agregue el campo `total` ya que tu estructura de tabla indica que no debe ser `NULL` (por ende en los `bindparam` asigne que fuera 0, pero si hay un valor calculado incluir ahi). En la posición del `id` se indica `NULL` ya que es autoincremental.

Comment: Otra cosa el formato de `$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` es un `datetime` y no un `date`. Asi que te recomiendo cambiarlo en tu tabla.

Comment: si es que total es la suma del JSON que ya lo tengo pero en solo lo muestrea en el JavaScript no lo he mandado ni convertido a json lo que me interesa ahorita es que el array se guarde ya después veré como le hago con la suma ./

Comment: ya corregí lo de la fecha . no entendí muy bien lo que tengo que hacer con lo que pusiste anteriormente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112720/discussion-between-ricardo-campos-villarroel-and-bryan-rl).